# AfterScroll and AfterOpen on TQuery

Tags: delphi, c++builder, vcl, bde

My application has a TQuery component where I need to do stuff in its AfterScroll() event:

```
void __fastcall TFormMain::Query1AfterScroll(TDataSet *DataSet)
{
    // do stuff here...
}
```

The problem is that the AfterScroll event is obviously fired twice when I do the following:

```
Query1->Active = true; // first call to AfterScroll 
Query1->Locate( /* some arguments here */ ); // second call
```

Note: Modification the SQL Query instead of Locate() is NO option

The first call to AfterScroll is the one I don't want to handle so I am looking for an elegant way to only handle the second one.

One of my first ideas were to use the AfterOpen() event to connect the AfterScroll Event handler on the fly:

```
__fastcall TFormMain::TFormMain(TComponent* Owner)
: TForm(Owner)
{
    Query1->AfterScroll = 0;
}

void __fastcall TFormMain::Query1AfterOpen(TDataSet *DataSet)
{
     Query1->AfterScroll = Query1AfterScroll;
}
```

This solution looks good, but doesn't work because AfterScroll will be called right at the moment when AfterOpen is left.

*Edit:*

*I am aware that I could set some flags to supress the code in AfterScroll from Executing (which is what I do right now (and: how it is described in the first answer below)), but I thougt there should be a more elegant and less error-prone way to go.*

*But after some research I am afraid that there is no better solution around.*

My question now is:

What is the proper way to catch the right AfterScroll call? (the one that is  called after Locate(...) )

Comment: Query1->AfterScroll = 0; Query1->Active = true; Query1->AfterScroll = Query1AfterScroll; Query1->Locate;

Answer (score 2):

The Delphi code below overrides the standard behaviour of a TAdoQuery (but should work
with any other TDataSet descendant that supports `Locate()`) so that the `AfterScroll` event is **only** called immediately
after a call to `TAdoQuery.Locate`.

Basically, it overrides the TAdoQuery `DoAfterScroll` so that the inherited method is only called when a boolean flag `FHandleScrollAfterLocate` is set.  `DoAfterScroll` is the TDataSet method which is used to call any `AfterScroll` handler which has been set up.  The flag is set to True in the overridden `Locate` function and is cleared each time `DoAfterScroll` is called.

I am sure you will get the idea if you want to change the conditions under which `AfterScroll` is called.

```
  type
    TAdoQuery = class(ADODB.TAdoQuery)
    private
      FHandleScrollAfterLocate: Boolean;
    protected
      property HandleScrollAfterLocate : Boolean read FHandleScrollAfterLocate;
      function Locate(const KeyFields: string; const KeyValues: Variant;
        Options: TLocateOptions): Boolean; override;
      procedure DoAfterScroll; override;
    public
    end;

    TForm1 = class(TForm)
      DataSource1: TDataSource;
      DBGrid1: TDBGrid;
      DBNavigator1: TDBNavigator;
      ADOConnection1: TADOConnection;
      AdoQuery1: TADOQuery;
      AdoQuery1ID: TIntegerField;
      AdoQuery1name: TStringField;
      btnLocate: TButton;
    [etc]
    [...]

    { TAdoQuery }

    procedure TAdoQuery.DoAfterScroll;
    begin
      try
        if FHandleScrollAfterLocate then
          inherited;
      finally
        FHandleScrollAfterLocate := False;
      end;
    end;

    function TAdoQuery.Locate(const KeyFields: string;
      const KeyValues: Variant; Options: TLocateOptions): Boolean;
    begin
      FHandleScrollAfterLocate := True;
      Result := inherited Locate(KeyFields, KeyValues, Options);
    end;

    procedure TForm1.AdoQuery1AfterScroll(DataSet: TDataSet);
    begin
      Caption := 'Scrolled';
    end;

    procedure TForm1.btnLocateClick(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      AdoQuery1.Locate('ID', 5, []);
    end;
```

Comment: @Herwig: "...answer below...I am afraid that there is no better solution around."  Well, at least my answer provides a way to do it which does not require the coder to remember to include code in the project's events to provide the required behaviour.